# Fitting negative binomial distribution to large count data

Tags: r, statistical-significance, goodness-of-fit, negative-binomial-distribution

I have a ~1 million data points. Here is the link to file [data.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6tiqu12vd2h471d/data.txt?dl=0) Each of them can take a value between 0 to 145. It's a discrete dataset. Below is the histogram of dataset. On x-axis is the count (0-145) and on y-axis is the density.

**source of data**: I have around 20 reference objects and 1 Million random object in the space. For each of these 1 million random objects i calculated Manhattan distance with respect to these 20 reference objects. However i only considered shortest distance among these 20 reference objects. So i have 1 million Manhattan distances (which you can find in the link to file given in post)

I tried to fit the Poisson and Negative binomial distributions to this data set using R. I found the fit resulting from the negative binomial distributions seems reasonable. Below is the fitted curve (in blue).

**Final goal**: Once i have fitted this distribution appropriately, i would like to considered this distribution as random distribution of distances. Next time when I calculate the distance (d) of the any object to these 20 reference objects, I should be able to know if the (d) is significant or just part of random distribution.

[image]

To evaluate the goodness of fit I calculated the chi squared test using R with the observed frequencies and probabilities I got from negative binomial fit. **Although the blue curve nicely fit to distribution, P-value returning from the chi squared test is extremely low.**

This put me in confusion a bit. I have two related questions:

1. Is the choice of negative binomial distribution for this dataset appropriate?
2. If the chi squared test P-value is so low, should I consider another distribution?

Below is the complete code I used:

```
# read the file containing count data
data <- read.csv("data.txt", header=FALSE)

# plot the histogram
hist(data[[1]], prob=TRUE, breaks=145)

# load library
library(fitdistrplus)

# fit the negative binomial distribution
fit <- fitdist(data[[1]], "nbinom")

# get the fitted densities. mu and size from fit.
fitD <- dnbinom(0:145, size=25.05688, mu=31.56127)

# add fitted line (blue) to histogram
lines(fitD, lwd="3", col="blue")

# Goodness of fit with the chi squared test  
# get the frequency table
t <- table(data[[1]])   

# convert to dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(t)

# get frequencies
observed_freq <- df$Freq

# perform the chi-squared test
chisq.test(observed_freq, p=fitD)
```

Comment: I see only 2 questions. Was there a 3rd? You say the data "can take a value between 0 to 145". Is this a number of of a fixed possible total (145)?

Comment: Outliers. You see a tail (or, most probably, you do not see it, because there are only several values here) on the right. That's why. And actually you can see - your fitted line is biased because of these large guys on the right.

Comment: @gung: thanks for your reply. I mis-typed it, there are only two questions. 145: is not a fix possible total. Its a maximum value random variable can take.

Comment: Why is it the maximum value the variable can take?

Comment: @gung: well i found it after sampling for 1 million times (and thats the value I found).

Comment: It sounds like it just happens to be the max of this dataset, then. (If you were to draw independent samples of 1 million again, the sample max might be 144 or 146.) What are these data?

Comment: @GermanDemidov: thanks for your reply. Yes I realized that there is tail, but I don't think they are outliers, its just that probability of their occurrence is low.

Comment: @gung: Let me first explained what this dataset is: I have around 20 reference objects and 1 Million random object in the space. For each of these 1 million random objects i calculated Manhattan distance with respect to these 20 reference objects. However i only considered shortest distance among these 20 reference objects. So i have 1 million Manhattan distances (which you can find in the link to file given in post)

Comment: You need to add that information to the main text of the question, so that it isn't buried in the comments. Also, you should state what the original data / variables & observations were that you were distances between.

Comment: @user1275607 and what is the probability of this values, if you use fitted distribution as true? I bet that is so close to 0 so it can not be explained with the sample size. I guess you can consider values that can not occur randomly in the dataset of specified size "outliers" under $H_0$ - they are not from your model for sure. They really make your fitted distribution spoiled (it looks nice only from the first sight, it is clearly biased to the right).

Comment: @GermanDemidov: probabilities of right tail is almost closed to 0. Anyhow I am not much worried about how the right side tail. Do you think I can ignore them?

Comment: @user1275607 it depends. They are for sure not from your model (you can not expect such amount of big values by chance under $H_0$). But removal them will not really improve fitting quality. I did the analysis, everything that is bigger than ~85 is an outlier (can not be expected by chance under $H_0$), but the distribution is still a bit skewed.

Comment: @german Demindov: Thanks for answer. Then what one could do in this case? should i go for any other distributions? I checked the correlation (>0.9) between observed probabilities and theoretical probabilities from model and seems to be reasonable.

Comment: No, the answer given by @Björn is really good. Just continue with NB distribution and do not care about goodness-of-fit tests, but take into account that you have outliers. You can include covariates, but there is no guarantee that it will solve problem with fitting.

Comment: Data link gives 404 :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, goodness of fitness tests or tests for particular distributions will typically reject the null hypothesis given a sufficiently large sample size, because we are hardly ever in the situation, where data exactly arises from a particular distribution and we did also take into account all relevant (possibly unmeasured) covariates that explain further differences between subject/units. However, in practice such deviations can be pretty irrelevant and it is well known that many models can be used, even if their are some deviations from distributional assumptions (most famously regarding the normality of residuals in regression models with normal error terms).

Secondly, a negative binomial model is a relatively logical default choice for count data (that can only be $\geq 0$). We do not have that many details though and there might be obvious features of the data (e.g. regarding how it arises) that would suggest something more sophisticated. E.g. accounting for key covariates using negative binomial regression could be considered.

Comment: thanks for your reply. So I am going to stick to the negative binomial distribution.