# Goodness of fit with 1000 or more observations

Tags: goodness-of-fit

When we have a lot of observations (for example 1000), and we want to find a "valid" distribution, which test should we perform ? Or how should we do ?

Why the number of observations is important ? In fact, I noticed that when we have real data, it is difficult (or impossible) to find a perfect law to fit. However, when ploting the histogram, we can notice that one distribution can be not bad; but a result of a test is not relevant.

For example, in the following plot: we have a histogram and the density of a lognormal distribution, we "see" that this distribution is not bad. However the p-value of the chisq test is very law. (the number of observations is near 3000).

What's more: when we do the chisq test with a uniform distribution, we have a similar p-value. However, we can tell, visually, that a lognormal dist is much better than a uniform law.

[image]

So in this case, the chisq test rejects equally lognormal distribution and uniform distribution, whereas lognormal distribution is much better than uniform dist.

For me, in fact, I'd like to "find" a test that accepts the lognormal distribution. And for a uniforme law, this same test should reject it.
(I try to figure out if this article can help : http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~dhunter/asymp/fall2002/lectures/ln11.pdf)

Comment: I think is what you may be looking for [Look here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205403/fitting-negative-binomial-distribution-to-large-count-data)

Comment: Thank you very much. So, the solution is, as I understand, to do a linear regression and say that the slope should be 1 and intercept 0. The study (with statements for p value, R2, AIC etc), should give us the quality of the regression, thus the goodness of fit ? Thank you

Comment: It's not clear why you're not getting rejections; you don't provide enough detail to guess what you're actually doing, but even a lowly chi-squared goodness of fit test generally should be rejecting here.

Comment: Thank you Glen_b for your comment. According to p value, the lognormal distribution is rejected, as well as uniform law. However, I'd like to have a test that accepts the lognormal dist (since it is OK visually, and not OK, at all, obviously, for a uniform law). I reedited your question. Thank you

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "rejects equally." It's usually meaningless to compare p-values associated with two different null hypotheses.